Unexpected Multiple Triggers of sforce.opencti.onNavigationChange Listener Method
Dear Salesforce Support Team,
We have observed that the sforce.opencti.onNavigationChange listener method is being triggered three times, instead of the expected single occurrence, within our environment.
This occurs when a user navigates away from the Salesforce contact tab and then returns to it.
We are using OpenCTI API version 43.0("/support/api/43.0/lightning/opencti").
Could you please clarify why this might be happening and if there are any configuration adjustments or known issues related to this behavior?

Thank you for your assistance in investigating this matter.
Best regards,
Mihai

Be aware this this site isn't an official part of Salesforce. We're mostly just users of Salesforrce like yourself, volunteering our time and knowledge. If you think that this really is a bug that Salesforce needs to address, then you should open a support case with Salesforce directly. This help article should help point you in the right direction.
